# To take entries in a webform multiple times using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I have a webform with name 'audit-form' and it has a column in which we have to enter the number of observations.

```
<form id="audit-form" action="action.php" method="post">
    <label for="observ_count">Number of Observations</label>
    <textarea id="observ_count" name="Number_of_Obsevations"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Obsevations" id="audit_form_submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    const auditForm=document.getElementById("audit_form");
    const auditButton=document.getElementById("audit_form_submit");

    auditButton.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var noo = auditForm.Number_of_Observations.value;
        for(i=0;i<noo;i++)
        {
            if(i<noo-1)
            {
                window.location.assign('observ.html'); //html page to enter obsevations and next button at bottom
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.assign('observ1.html'); //html page to enter obsevations and submit button at bottom
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I tried to do this but directly observ1.html is opening up not observ.html
Please help

Comment: "I tried to do this...". What did you try to do? What is the desired behaviour of this code? Please include your problem description in more detail in your post. It is not clear what you are aiming for.

Comment: I mentioned it in pretty simple terms. I tried this logic but it isn't working the way I want. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You simple wrong here:

Look at name

```
<textarea id="observ_count" name="Number_of_Obsevations"></textarea>
```

And now look what you write in js:

```
var noo = auditForm.Number_of_Observations.value;
```

`Number_of_Obsevations` is not equal to `Number_of_Observations`

```js
const auditForm=document.getElementById("observ_count");
const auditButton=document.getElementById("audit_form_submit");

auditButton.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
e.preventDefault();
var noo = auditForm.value;
for(i=0;i<noo;i++)
{
if(i<noo-1)
{
console.log('1');
}
else
{
console.log('2');
}
}
})
```

```html
<form id="audit-form">
<label for="observ_count" Number of Obsevations</label>
<textarea id="observ_count" name="Number_of_Obsevations"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add Obsevations" id="audit_form_submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It was a typo error while mentioning in the question. Help me find the correct script code for the same

Comment: i add a snippet see please.

Comment: In this, we are just printing a variable, but I have to run a completely separate web form in the loop

Comment: i do with console log because you can see how that work but you can change with redirect page.

Comment: I want to know what command or logic to use, as I am not able to think of one.

Comment: Not redirect, to run the next web page in a loop

Comment: this script work, how can you see in console log if you insert 5 for example log is : `1-1-1-1-2` , so if you open new page for example will open `observ.html-observ.html-observ.html-observ.html-observ1.html`